# Running tns resources generate icons killed iOS app

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I ran `tns resources generate splashes` and `tns resources generate icons` and it worked fine for Android but when it reloaded on iOS I got the following error:

> /* com.apple.actool.errors */
>   /Users/adam_beck/Desktop/code/fingoalNS/platforms/ios/fingoalNS/Resources/Assets.xcassets: error: None of the input catalogs contained a matching stickers icon set or app icon set named  "AppIcon".
>   /* com.apple.actool.document.warnings */
>   /Users/adam_beck/Desktop/code/fingoalNS/platforms/ios/fingoalNS/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./LaunchScreen.AspectFill.imageset/(null)[2d][LaunchScreen-AspectFill.png]: warning: The image set "LaunchScreen.AspectFill" has 2 unassigned children.
>   /Users/adam_beck/Desktop/code/fingoalNS/platforms/ios/fingoalNS/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./LaunchScreen.Center.imageset/(null)[2d][LaunchScreen-Center.png]: warning: The image set "LaunchScreen.Center" has 2 unassigned children.
>   /Users/adam_beck/Desktop/code/fingoalNS/platforms/ios/fingoalNS/Resources/Assets.xcassets:./LaunchImage.launchimage/(null)[2d][Default-1125h.png]: warning: The launch image set "LaunchImage" has 12 unassigned children.
>   /* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
>   /Users/adam_beck/Desktop/code/fingoalNS/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fingoalNS.app/LaunchImage-700-568h@2x.png
>   /Users/adam_beck/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fingoalNS-fvoglrpadrrtljalueomxfllvudt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/fingoalNS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fingoalNS.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist

When I rebuilt for iOS I got the following error:

> Failed to find LaunchScreen.storyboard but it was specified in the Info.plist.
>   Consider updating the resources in app/App_Resources/iOS/.
>   A good starting point would be to create a new project and diff the changes with your current one.
>   Also the following repo may be helpful: https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world/tree/master/App_Resources/iOS
>   We will now place an empty obsolete compatability white screen LauncScreen.xib for you in platforms/ios/fingoalNS/Resources/LaunchScreen.xib so your app may appear as it did in pre v2.1.0 versions of the ios runtime.
>   Info.plist: Merging CFBundleURLTypes: Property CFBundleTypeRole is required!

and it exits with `Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case any one else runs into this issue the `tns` commands never worked but I was able to successfully generate splashes and icons through Sidekick. From their docs:

1. Launch NativeScript Sidekick and open your app.
2. From the left toolbar, select Assets to open the Assets view.
3. To generate the icons of your app, complete the following steps.

   1. In the icon placeholder in the generator, click Browse.
   2. Browse and locate the image source that you want to use, select it and click Open.
   3. When prompted, choose for which platforms you want to generate icons.
   4. Click Generate and wait for the operation to complete.
4. To generate the splash screens of your app, complete the following steps.

   1. In the splash screen placeholder in the generator, click Browse.
   2. Browse and locate the image source that you want to use, select it and click Open.
   3. When prompted, choose for which platforms you want to generate splash screens.
   4. (Optional) Provide a custom background color in a hexadecimal format.
   5. Click Generate and wait for the operation to complete.
5. (Optional) Select the Android and iOS tabs to inspect the newly added app assets.

Comment: For iOS it doesn't work either. iOS app crashes after doing the icon setting. Also, splash screen settings for iOS ends ok but it is not shown at all on Simulator. At least it does not brake the app.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows and this command worked perfectly:

```
tns resources generate icons app-icon.png
```

I putted icon in the main folder, so it didn't required to give a path or smth..
Same with splashes:

```
tns resources generate splashes app-icon.png --background white
```